# Set environment variables for non-interactive shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to set environment variables for non-interactive non-login shell. I know bash reads the contents of ~/.bashrc before execute the command. In the beginning of the script there's a part:

```
*# If not running interactively, don't do anything

case $- in
*i*) ;;
  *) return;;
esac*
```

So I think if I add something above it, it will take effect no matter if the shell is interactive or not:

```
export VAR=something

# If not running interactively, don't do anything

case $- in
*i*) ;;
  *) return;;
esac
```

However it doesn't work :(. I want to avoid using $BASH_ENV because it messes up my xkb settings. I remapped some keys in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc. And if I set $BASH_ENV, it will just loads the default keymap.

Comment: Why does setting `BASH_ENV` mess with your xkb settings? Are you setting it to a filename with code for changing your key layout? Have you tried not doing that?

Comment: I set $BASH_ENV to a script that has a few "export" in order to have some default environment variables. There's nothing related to xkb in that

Comment: Sorry that I assumed incorrectly. XKB still works fine. The problem is with the ~/.xbindkeysrc. I have a line to run it in the rc.local file, and when BASH_ENV is set, that doesn't work. But I just want to know why adding export VAR=something doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to set a variable in ~/.bashrc and when using "ssh host script" the variable was available for use. Could you please detail your scenario more precisely.

Comment: Well czvtools, you can read the https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html, invoked non-interactively. I'm trying to execute a script when run the shell non-interactively by setting BASH_ENV. But it doesn't work. And I think my xbindkeys has been affected by a side effect

Comment: What do you set BASH_ENV to?

Comment: The behavior is random as sometimes xbindkeys -p (the command to activate it) runs and sometimes doesn't. Also I get some "System detected warnings" when the computer starts as well.

Comment: it's a script is /mybin/bash.sh (with execution permission).

Comment: Ok. Solution for Ubuntu: set the variables in /etc/environment, and it works for all users and all types of shells ... If only I had known that in the beginning.

Comment: @TrungQuanVo please make your last comment as answer for this.

Comment: Also please make sure no env variables are filtered out by sudoers configuration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution for Ubuntu: set the variables in `/etc/environment`, and it works for all users and all types of shells.

Comment: So it's not possible to set user-specific environment variables for non-interactive shell?

Comment: perhaps that's a bit of an edge case wrt the question, but if you run bash in a ubuntu container, i.e. `docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash`, then /etc/environment is completely ignored. I'm not aware of a mode to have that file loaded up, other than using BASH_ENV

Comment: @wuarmin apparently the answer is BASH_ENV. Please check https://serverfault.com/a/593487/951855

Answer (score 2):

The details are somewhat platform-dependent. [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the reference manual describes the default behavior of Bash itself; but you also need to take into account the behavior of your particular platform.

In general, `$HOME/.bashrc` is executed for non-interactive *login* shells, but no script can be guaranteed to run for a non-interactive non-login shell.  You can force it by setting (and exporting!) `BASH_ENV` from a parent shell to the name of a script which you want to execute when a non-interactive shell is started.

Sometimes, an acceptable workaround is to run a script in a login shell, and trust that the non-interactive non-login script you run inherits whatever parameters you set in the login shell.  This is what e.g. `/etc/environment` can do; but it does not force a piece of script to run at the time when a noninteractive shell is subsequently started (except of course if you use `/etc/environment` to set up `BASH_ENV` as described above).