# How to set environment variable for non-interactive shell in docker container?

Tags: python, linux, docker, pycharm

I'm using command `docker run -e GRB_WLSACCESSID=xxxxxxx` to set environment variables for Gurobi authorization. The OS of container is Ubuntu 16.04. This is OK if I login the container via SSH interactively and read the environment variables by python code `os.getenv()`.

But, when I add this container as remote SSH interpreter in Pycharm and execute the python code along Pycharm, I can't get the environment variables.

At last I found the problem is that the environment variables generated by `docker run -e` can only be read by interactive shell. This can be validated by executing `ssh root@x.x.x.x env`, and interactively execute `env` after logging into the container. The former outputs less.

One possible solution is write some configuration manually after the container is generated, e.g., set the variables in `/etc/environment` (provided by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725538/set-environment-variables-for-non-interactive-shell)).

The other possible solution is add the variables manually in Pycharm `edit configuration`.

Is there a more elegant solution? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood the specific meaning of the [relevant answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686564/how-to-keep-environment-variables-for-remote-python-interpreter-with-pycharm)

It means, in the remote VM or container, create a linux script file named `mypython` as the python wrapper with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
/path/to/interpreter/bin/python "$@"
```

, where `/path/to/interpreter/bin/python` is the path to the python interpreter. For conda interpreter, it might look like `/root/miniconda3/envs/py37/bin/python`.

The script `mypython` should be placed in the same path as binary `python`, i.e., `/root/miniconda3/envs/py37/bin/mypython`

And then add the execute permission to `mypython`:

```
chmod +x /root/miniconda3/envs/py37/bin/mypython
```

The above two steps can also be executed by command as an alternative:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash -l
/root/miniconda3/envs/py37/bin/python "$@"' > /root/miniconda3/envs/py37/bin/mypython
chmod +x /root/miniconda3/envs/py37/bin/mypython
```

At last, add the SSH interpreter in Pycharm, make sure the interpreter path is `/root/miniconda3/envs/py37/bin/mypython`

And the problem is solved.